# hamburgerMenu is not working using selenium

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Website Link: https://catevolution.com.au/

HTML code:

```html
<div id="top" class="full-width">
   <div class="background-top"></div>
   <div class="background">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
      <div class="pattern">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4" id="header-left">
                  <div class="logo"><a href="https://catevolution.com.au"><img title="Cat Evolution" alt="Cat Evolution" nitro-lazy-src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/image/catalog/donelogo.jpg" class=" lazyloaded" nitro-lazy-empty="" src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/image/catalog/donelogo.jpg"></a></div>
                  <div class="sec"><a href="https://catevolution.com.au"><img title="Cat Evolution" alt="Cat Evolution" nitro-lazy-src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/image/catalog/donelogo.jpg" class=" ls-is-cached lazyloaded" nitro-lazy-empty="" src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/image/catalog/donelogo.jpg"></a></div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-8" id="header-right">
                  <div class="search_form">
                     <div class="button-search"></div>
                     <div class="search-cat">
                        <div class="select">
                           <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                              <option value="0">All categories</option>
                              <option value="67">Contempocat Trees</option>
                              <option value="71">Litter-Robot Connect</option>
                              <option value="60">Litter-Robot III Open Air</option>
                              <option value="65">Petfun</option>
                              <option value="70">Smart Pet Feeder</option>
                              <option value="72">Tofu Cat Litter</option>
                              <option value="74">Workshop Spares</option>
                              <option value="75">Workshop Spares</option>
                              <option value="57">MEYOU UNIQUE DESIGNER CAT BEDS | CAT PODS</option>
                              <option value="17">Premium Clumping Cat Litter</option>
                              <option value="61">Litter-Robot Accessories</option>
                              <option value="73">Reconditioned Litter-Robots</option>
                              <option value="64">FELLI PET</option>
                              <option value="62">Litter Robot Components</option>
                              <option value="68">Contempocat Spares</option>
                              <option value="69">Track Courier</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="overflow-input"><input type="text" class="input-block-level search-query" name="search" placeholder="Search" id="search_query" value=""></div>
                     <div id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-results"></div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="https://catevolution.com.au/index.php?route=account/account" class="my-account"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> 
                  <div class="resp-accountq"> <a href="https://catevolution.com.au/index.php?route=account/account" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://catevolution.com.au/index.php?route=account/account'" class="my-account qa-account" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> </div>
                  <div id="cart_block" class="dropdown">
                     <div class="cart-heading dropdown-toogle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://catevolution.com.au/index.php?route=checkout/cart'">
                        <i class="cart-count"><span id="total_count_ajax">0</span></i> <i class="cart-icon"><img alt="" nitro-lazy-src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/catalog/view/theme/fastor/img/icon-cart-hover.png" class="cart-icon-hover lazyloaded" nitro-lazy-empty="" src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/catalog/view/theme/fastor/img/icon-cart-hover.png"><img alt="" nitro-lazy-src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/catalog/view/theme/fastor/img/icon-cart.png" class="cart-icon-standard lazyloaded" nitro-lazy-empty="" src="https://nitrocdn.com/ZBTgCclWrYZojiCeCJknQxXkexTesFSn/assets/static/optimized/rev-66b43b2/catalog/view/theme/fastor/img/icon-cart.png"></i> 
                        <p><strong id="total_price_ajax"><span id="total_price">$0.00</span></strong></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" id="cart_content">
                        <div id="cart_content_ajax">
                           <div class="empty">Your shopping cart is empty!</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="megamenu-background">
            <div class="">
               <div class="overflow-megamenu container">
                  <div id="megamenu_33871725" class="container-megamenu container horizontal">
                     <div class="megaMenuToggle">
                        <div class="megamenuToogle-wrapper">
                           <div class="megamenuToogle-pattern">
                              <div class="container">
                                 <div id="burger_menu_sel"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                                 Navigation 
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="megamenu-wrapper">
                        <div class="megamenu-pattern">
                           <div class="container">
                              <ul class="megamenu flipping">
                                 <li class=" with-sub-menu hover">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu"></p>
                                    <a href="litter-robot-iii-open-air.html" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Litter Robot</strong></span></a>
                                    <div class="sub-menu " style="width:750px;">
                                       <div class="content">
                                          <p class="arrow"></p>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="litter-robot-iii-open-air.html">Automatic Self Cleaning Litter-Robot</a> </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="litter-robot-3-connect.html">Litter-Robot Connect</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="litter-robot-accessories">Accessories</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="litter-robot-components.html">Litter Robot Components</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="reconditioned-litter-robots">Reconditioned Litter-Robots</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class=" with-sub-menu hover">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu"></p>
                                    <a href="contempocat-trees" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Cat Tower</strong></span></a>
                                    <div class="sub-menu full-width-sub-menu" style="width:100%;">
                                       <div class="content">
                                          <p class="arrow"></p>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="contempocat-trees/elevation-cat-tree">Elevation Cat Tower</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="contempocat-trees/elevation-jr-cat-tower">Elevation Jr Cat Tower</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="contempocat-trees/contoure-cat-tower">Contoure Cat Tree</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class=" with-sub-menu hover">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu"></p>
                                    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Feeders &amp; Fountains</strong></span></a>
                                    <div class="sub-menu " style="width:750px;">
                                       <div class="content">
                                          <p class="arrow"></p>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="autofeeder.html">Auto Pet Feeder with Camera</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="pet-water-fountain.html">Filtered Water Fountain</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="W1_filter_replacement.html">Petwant Filter Replacement</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="smart-water-bowl">Smart Water Fountain</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="water-bowl-filter">Petfun Water Replacement Filters</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu mobile-disabled"></p>
                                    <a href="meyou" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Meyou Cat Bed</strong></span></a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu mobile-disabled"></p>
                                    <a href="felli-pet-bowls" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Felli Pet Bowls</strong></span></a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class=" with-sub-menu hover">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu"></p>
                                    <a href="premium-clumping-cat-litter.html" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Cat Litter</strong></span></a>
                                    <div class="sub-menu full-width-sub-menu" style="width:100%;">
                                       <div class="content">
                                          <p class="arrow"></p>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="premium-clumping-cat-litter.html">Premium Clumping Cat Litter</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="tofu-carbon-cat-litter.html">Tofu + Carbon Clumping Cat Litter</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="border"></div>
                                          <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled"><a href="https://catevolution.com.au/moshizon-clumping-cat-litter.html">Moshizon Clay Clumping Litter</a></div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="">
                                    <p class="close-menu"></p>
                                    <p class="open-menu mobile-disabled"></p>
                                    <a href="index.php?route=extension/module/productbundles/listing" class="clearfix"><span><strong>Specials</strong></span></a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <template data-nitro-marker-id="9a234f5d0645013a62b0b6769ff33645-1"></template>
                  <script src="blob:https://catevolution.com.au/a4f12dbf-ab12-499b-bfa9-6f974ce9caaf" data-nitro-for-id="9a234f5d0645013a62b0b6769ff33645-1" type="text/javascript" id="9a234f5d0645013a62b0b6769ff33645-1"></script> 
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have written tests using Selenium WebDriver and I have problems with opening menu bar in mobile view.

[Link](http://prnt.sc/11drp22) to hamburger menu locator.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]")).click();
```

I tried all all method to click on menu but its not working.
Method I try to click on menu

1. cssselector
2. xpath

Comment: Please check the screen shot.https://prnt.sc/11drp22

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This `CSS` selector

`.megaMenuToggle.active>.megamenuToogle-wrapper>.megamenuToogle-pattern>.container>div`

should work and you need to wait until it is clickable.
This one should work better: the first one was for an active element:

```
header:nth-of-type(1) .megamenuToogle-pattern>.container>div
```

**Explanation**:

1 `header:nth-of-type(1)` - the first element with the name header

2 `.megamenuToogle-pattern` class with the name `megamenuToogle-pattern`, not a direct child

3 `>.container>div`- direct child class of class `megamenuToogle-pattern` and its direct child `div`. You use > char to show that the element is a direct child.

Comment: This is the error occure after using Css seelctor.  I have increase the sleep time for wait but not workin.      Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".megaMenuToggle.active>.megamenuToogle-wrapper>.megamenuToogle-pattern>.container>div"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.93)

Comment: I want to ask how you create that Css Selector path. The same error occurred again.Please suggest me any solution to get rid of this error.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this error occur. Sometime its working fine with same code and sometime its generating error.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing a code or execution process. I may only guess. My first guess is that you may need to add some waits. Use time.sleep() for debugging.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("header:nth-of-type(1) .megamenuToogle-pattern>.container>div\r\n")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("We have clicked on hamburger menu");   This is the peace of code I use for clicking on burger menu. Than I want to click on sub menu but but sub menu not open

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_ktRlEXN3LMFJqh9CNSUli3gQ-bOP8v/view?usp=sharing          In the video you can see the process

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these Xpath expressions:

- "//div[@class='megamenuToggle-wrapper']"

Or:

- "//div[contains(text(),'Navigation')]"

Comment: Both xpath not working and error display on screen is      Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'Navigation')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.93)

Comment: Try value() instead of text(), and also "//div[@value='Navigation']"